# How can I get order details of specific product in Magento 2.x?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, customer, sales-order

I want the detail of orders for a specific product and get the customers detail that which customer had purchased that specified product. How can I know that in Magento 2?

For example: I am having product Chair in my M2 store. I need to know how many orders had been made of that particular product. And how could I know that which customers had purchased that product 'chair'?

Comment: where and how you want this information, i mean you need to create one interface for this?

Comment: Hi @Hiren, thanks for your reply. I need to know the detail of orders made for a particular order. It can be anywhere in admin or by using a custom script. I just need to know the number of orders made of that specified product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this sql query in your database

```
SELECT so.customer_email, soi.sku, soi.name FROM `sales_order` as so left join sales_order_item as soi on so.entity_id = soi.order_id where soi.sku = 'your_product_sku'
```

Replace **your_product_sku** with your product actual sku. You can create script also.

Please let me know still if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks @user55548. I got created a custom script and used this query to fetch the records and it gave me what I needed. Thanks alot.